# Is it possible to open for example facebook.com page in browsersync?

Tags: browser-sync

I need to open one page on multiple devices, but I'm not developer (I don't have project of the site) and I want use existing page like facebook.com. Is it possible with browsersync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are able to open any webadress on the web.

You have to have installed 2 main things though.

1. You have to have installed Node. Here is a good working guide. [How
   to install npm and node](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-mac)
2. You have to install browser-sync on your
   machine like so:

   ```
   npm install -g browser-sync
   ```

After you have everything installed you can run this command in terminal like so:

```
browser-sync start -p "https://facebook.com"
```

After running you should get a result like this one:

```
[BS] Proxying: https://facebook.com
[BS] Access URLs:
--------------------------------------
Local: https://localhost:3000
External: https://192.168.1.143:3000
--------------------------------------
UI: http://localhost:3001
UI External: http://192.168.1.143:3001
```